# Bash loop for adding --exclude list to tar

Tags: linux, bash, encryption, tar, bash-scripting

I have a [bash script](https://github.com/ctorix/encrypt-decrypt/blob/master/encrypt-decrypt.sh) I made to encrypt/decrypt using GPG and tar.  Right now I have my `--exclude` hard coded into the script, but I'd like to make it a bit more dynamic and add the items to exclude as arguments when running the encrypt part of the script.

Basically I'm trying to figure out a loop (or other option) to replace the exclusions below with argument values.  Right now the arguments are assigned as follows:

`$1`=Source
`$2`=Destination
`$3`=Filename
`$4`=Recipient's public gpg key

What I'd like to accomplish is any arguments supplied for `$5` and up be set as excluded files/directories.

I've searched all over for loop options to create a variable concatenating `--exclude` and the supplied value, but I'm coming up empty.  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
tar -cpJ --exclude ~/VirtualBox_VMs --exclude ~/Truecrypt_Volumes ${SOURCE} | gpg -e -r ${RECIPIENT} -o ${SAVEAS}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/192249/2947502

Comment: could use a temp file containing all the excludes too

Answer (score 1):

There are two relevant tricks here: you can get the arguments starting at `$5` using a trick similar to array slicing (`"${@:5}"`), then build the list of `--exclude` arguments as an array, and use `"${array[@]}"` to include them in the command line.

```
excludes=()    # start with an empty array
for excl in "${@:5}"; do    # for each extra argument...
    excludes+=(--exclude "$excl")    # add an exclude to the array
done

tar -cpJ "${excludes[@]}" "${SOURCE}" ...
```

Comment: This works perfectly for what I need to accomplish.  Thank you very much!